# Emergency mode using some kernels in CentOS

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, systemd-journald

I did some mistake of fiddling with an old VirtualBox installation, trying to build kernel modules. I got rid of dkms. Still, I have the strange problem that the two latest kernel I have results in emergency mode, while the third one boots succesfully.

```
kernel-3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
```

yield emergency mode, while

```
kernel-3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
```

boots properly.

Upon advice I saved the journal file, see https://pastebin.com/SB1JzBcS

Someone spot a failing `/dev/sdb1` but when I booted properly, fsck found it right.

What can cause this error?